# Google maps - angular error - Unhandled Promise rejection: Maximum call stack size exceeded ;

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

We tried migrating our application from angular 8 to angular 15 and facing issues with google maps.

Below are the versions of libraries from npm included.

```
"@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
"@types/googlemaps": "3.39.12",
"agm-direction": "^0.8.10",
```

We are using node 18.10.0 and Angular 15.2.0

When including the below snippet of code in app component we are getting Maximum call stack size exceeded error.

```
<agm-map [latitude]="3.115000009536743" [longitude]="101.57009887695312" [zoom]="10">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="3.115000009536743" [longitude]="101.57009887695312 "></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Error

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Maximum call stack size exceeded ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at _global.<computed>.get (zone.js:945:25)
    at _global.<computed>.get (zone.js:945:36)
    at _global.<computed>.get (zone.js:945:36)
    at _global.<computed>.get (zone.js:945:36)
    at _global.<computed>.get (zone.js:945:36)
    at _global.<computed>.get (zone.js:945:36)
    at _global.<computed>.get (zone.js:945:36)
    at _global.<computed>.get (zone.js:945:36)
    at _global.<computed>.get (zone.js:945:36)
    at _global.<computed>.get (zone.js:945:36) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at _global.<computed>.get (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8133:13)
    at _global.<computed>.get (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8133:24)
    at _global.<computed>.get (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8133:24)
    at _global.<computed>.get (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8133:24)
    at _global.<computed>.get (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8133:24)
    at _global.<computed>.get (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8133:24)
    at _global.<computed>.get (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8133:24)
    at _global.<computed>.get (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8133:24)
    at _global.<computed>.get (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8133:24)
    at _global.<computed>.get (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8133:24)
```

We have configured AgmCoreModule in AppModule.

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey : <google maps key>
}),
```

Sample project can be found below.

https://github.com/haribalaji89/googlemaps-error

To run the project, need to do

npm install --force

nvm\v18.10.0\node.exe --max_old_space_size=10240 .\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng serve --configuration=my-dev

When connecting to http://localhost:4200 will find stacktrace in developer console.

Comment: Resolved the issue. index.my.html has a older version of zone.min.js. Upgrading from 0.9.1 to 0.12.0 worked.